# JSON dump echo specific data only

Tags: php, json

So I have a JSON dump that looks like this:

```
{"LTC":{"PHP":2568.85},"ETH":{"PHP":18688.15},"IOT":{"PHP":29.91},"XRP":{"PHP":16.62},"BTC":{"PHP":154192.66}}
```

But I want to echo, for example ETH's PHP value only in a specific div. Then BTC's PHP value on another unique div.

So I did this for BTC:

```
echo $json['PHP']->BTC;
```

And this for ETH:

```
echo $json['PHP']->ETH;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Where did I go wrong?

It's now working. Thanks for all your answers. :D

Comment: Did you parse the JSON? Also, separately, note that there is no top-level property in that structure with the name `PHP`.

Comment: Yes. But I parsed it wrongly before. I did $json = json_decode($json,TRUE); instead of just $json = json_decode($json);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but to get your right output, you just need to use:

```
<?php
  $json = '{"LTC":{"PHP":2568.85},"ETH":{"PHP":18688.15},"IOT":{"PHP":29.91},"XRP":{"PHP":16.62},"BTC":{"PHP":154192.66}}';
  $json = json_decode($json);
  echo $json->ETH->PHP;
  echo $json->ETH->BTC;
?>
```

Comment: This is the API URL https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,LTC,XRP,BTC&tsyms=PHP and I want to echo the PHP values of each currency in specific divs. But I don't want to use a forech loop. 

Comment: @jehzlau Checking it.

Comment: @jehzlau Changed the first line to `$json = file_get_contents("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=ETH,LTC,XRP,BTC&tsyms=PHP");`. Works as expected... 

Comment: Hi Praveen. It works now. Im calling it as an array, i forgot to remove the TRUE after json in json_decode. It works now! 

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is that you try to access $json as an array, when it is an object. Also, you got the order of PHP and ETH wrong (you have to call the outermost key first):

```
$json = json_decode('{"LTC":{"PHP":2568.85},"ETH":{"PHP":18688.15},"IOT":{"PHP":29.91},"XRP":{"PHP":16.62},"BTC":{"PHP":154192.66}}');

print_r($json);

echo $json->ETH->PHP
```

Comment: yeah, if I use print_r it shows this Array ( [ETH] => Array ( [PHP] => 18611.05 ) [LTC] => Array ( [PHP] => 2561.14 ) [XRP] => Array ( [PHP] => 16.65 ) [BTC] => Array ( [PHP] => 154192.66 ) )

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code

```
    <?php


    $json = '{"LTC":{"PHP":2568.85},"ETH":{"PHP":18688.15},"IOT":
    {"PHP":29.91},"XRP":{"PHP":16.62},"BTC":{"PHP":154192.66}}';

    $json = json_decode($json);


    echo $json->ETH->PHP;

    echo '<br/>';
    echo $json->BTC->PHP;
```